# $\prod_{i\in A} B=(A\to B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Moschovakis Exercise **x4.3**:

> Prove that for sets $A,B$, $$\prod_{i\in A} B=(A\to B)$$
>   where $(A\to B)$ is the set of functions $A\to B$.

The product is defined for an **indexed family of sets**:

> An indexed family of sets is a function $A=(i\mapsto A_i)_{i\in I}:I\to E$ for some  $I\ne \emptyset$ and some $E$, where each $A_i$ is a set. The product of an indexed family of sets $A$ as above is $$\prod_{i\in I} A_i=\{f:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i: (\forall i\in I)(f(i)\in A_i)\}$$

and the union, which is present in the definition of the product, is also defined for an indexed family of sets:

> $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=\{x\in \bigcup E:(\exists i\in I)(x\in A_i)\}$

However, $B$ is not an indexed family of sets. Then how am I supposed to prove $\prod_{i\in A} B=(A\to B)$; in particular, how to interpret the LHS?

Comment: The interpretation is the indexed family $(X_i:i\in A)$ where $X_i=B$ for all $i\in A$.

Comment: I'm not sure why they require $I\neq\varnothing$...

Comment: @DerekElkins I borrowed this definition (and the exercise) from Moschovakis.

Comment: @logic As a general note, you should include citations to the text that you are quoting in the question to make easier for people to provide better answers, to make it more easily found by other people who might be using that text, and as a small form of giving credit. That said, the "they" that I was referring to was the (unknown to me at the time) author(s) of the text. The $I\neq\varnothing$ constraint is completely unnecessary unless (which is likely) the authors have other unnecessary restrictions to non-empty sets in the underlying concepts, e.g. $\bigcup$.

Answer (score 1):

Following the clarification by Andrés E. Caicedo:

$B$ is the family of sets $B=(i\mapsto B)_{i\in A}:A\to E$ where $E$ is a set such that $B\in E$. (I think, strictly speaking, the first $B$ above should be replaced by another symbol like $\hat B$ because it's not the same $B$ as the $B$ in $i\mapsto B$.)

Now $$\bigcup_{i\in A}B=\{x\in \bigcup E: x\in B\}=B.$$ So $$\prod_{i\in A} B=\{f:A\to B:(\forall i)(f(i)\in B)\}=\{f: A\to B\}=(A\to B).$$